# I want to access and modify XML file using JavaScript. After modifying it I need to save it. Please help!

Tags: javascript, xml

**Here is the xml file I want to modify -**

Note: Sorry somehow I cannot type '<'

```
<nsml version="-//iNEWS//DTD NSML 2.0//EN">

<head> meta wire=o words=347 rate=175> rgroup number=214> wgroup number=214>

<fields>

<f id=title> Title /f>

<f id=headline> Headline /f>

<f id=summary >Summary /f>

</fields>
```

**Here is my JavaScript code -**

```
 var xmlHttp=null;

 try {

   // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari

   xmlHttp=new xmlHttpRequest();

 }

 catch(e) {

   // Internet Explorer

   try {

         xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

    }

    catch (e) {

        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

 }

 xmlHttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);

 xmlHttp.send();

 xmlDoc=xmlHttp.responseXML; 

 x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("f")[0].childNodes[0]; /*says x is null or not an object */

 x.nodeValue="New Title";
```

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: JavaScript is `client side` meaning you can't directly save it—unless you set up a serverside script to do it for you.

Comment: Javascript isn't just client side, it can also be used server side, though this example looks client side.

Comment: My project requires me to either modify a XML file or create a new one similar to the one used above. I can use JavaScript/PHP. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify files only with javascript. Even if you can... why would you do it?

Comment: My project requires me to either modify a XML file or create a new one similar to the one used above. I can use JavaScript/PHP. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks again.